# STM32 Simulink Embedded Coder

Tags: matlab, embedded, stm32, simulink, clock

I am new to Simulink Embedded Coder. I have a custom STM32G473 board. I am flashing an LED. I've done this successfully with both C code, and generated from simulink.
I am trying to configure the clock. I have an external 16MHz oscillator. In STM32CubeMX, I configure the clock to go from the HSE to PLL and then the final PLL speed is 168MHz.
***My issue is*** that in Simulink (Hardware settings->target hardware resources), the CPU speed still shows at 16MHz. The box will not let me change this value. How can I get simulink to understand that the CPU speed is much faster? I'd like to avoid timing issues down the road.

I tried inputting several different clock values, restarting simulink, etc. No change. I want to make sure that I can actually run my processor at 168MHz and not 16MHz.